# Structured data is not taken into account for sharing via google+

Tags: share, google-plus

I see the google see correctly structured data but this data is not prepopulated in share dialog.
Data from google dev tool: 
rdfa-node
property:

```
image:  https://s3.amazonaws.com/&lt;bucket&gt;/images/image_200_200.JPG
title:  Sandal
url:    https://site.amazonaws.com/p/view/27
description:    description
type:   article
```

My meta tags:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://s3.amazonaws.com/<bucket>/images/image_200_200.JPG">
<meta property="og:title" content="Sandal">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://site.amazonaws.com/p/view/27">
<meta property="og:description" content="description">
<meta property="og:type" content="article">
```

code for calling the dialog:

```
<a class="gplus in-popup" sm_type="gplus" href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=https://site.amazonaws.com/p/view/27"></a>
```

Image is 200*200 px. I tried 900*900 and 120*120 - the same.
Everything looks good, but I still can see only url in the share dialog.
Is it possible that it is because image is from another host?
Maybe some other things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using snippet microdata? Use [the snippet tool on the Google+ developers page](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/snippet/) to generate it.

The following example illustrates how your Microdata would be entered:

```
<!-- Update your html tag to include the itemscope and itemtype attributes. -->
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">

<!-- Add the following three tags inside head. -->
<meta itemprop="name" content="Sandal">
<meta itemprop="description" content="description">
<meta itemprop="image" content="https://s3.amazonaws.com/&amp;lt;bucket&amp;gt;/images/image_200_200.JPG">
```